# Java Binary type in file

Tags: java, file, binary

I have a problem with binary type. I have binary file with data. Every element is split by "_".  I am using
`DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("C:/Data/"+names));` , where names is the name of my binary file. How I can read this file and saving elements in array? This is possible?

Comment: Is the file actually binary or just "encoded" using your convention of delimiting entries with an underscore?

Comment: Can you give a detailed description of the file format?

Comment: fyi the ascii code of `'_'` is `0x5f`

Comment: file format is name.hgt and in there is matrix 3x3. I need save elements this matrix to array

Comment: For future reference, a file format is not the name of the file, but how its contents are represented in the file.

Comment: oh sorry :) There are 2 byte ints

Comment: This is in big endian but I must convert to little endian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When writing to a binary file, there is no need to split each items in the matrix with '_'. The program knows how many bytes allocated for each item.

The following code write 2 doubles without '_' in between. After that, it reads them back from the file and output the data.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("a.bin"));
        dos.writeDouble(1.2);
        dos.writeDouble(3.4);
        dos.close();

        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("a.bin"));
        System.out.println(dis.readDouble());
        System.out.println(dis.readDouble());
        dis.close();
    }
}
```

The program outputs:

```
1.2
3.4
```

But if you didn't write the file and there is '_' between items, you can use `readChar()` after reading each item from the binary file as @Bhaskar already mentioned.

Finally, using `ObjectOutputStream` can write the whole array at once.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("a.bin"));
        double[] a = {1.2, 3.4};
        oos.writeObject(a);
        oos.close();

        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("a.bin"));
        double[] b = (double[]) ois.readObject();
        System.out.println(b[0]);
        System.out.println(b[1]);
        ois.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the data was written down into that file. If it was written using `DataOutputStream`'s `writeXXX()` where XXX stands for the actual data type of elements, and where elements were separated  by a `writeChar('_')` , then you can easily read them back using `DataInputStream`'s `readXXX()` method. Just make sure that you read the elements in the exact sequence that they were written , and also that you use `readChar()` whenever you expect the `-` to be present ( ie between two elements).

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `read(byte[])` or `read(byte[],ffset,length)` to read the content of file into byte array.